# Tuple Errors Python

Tags: python, tuples

I opened Python and attempted to run the following script (btw, this script is what was directly given to me, I haven't edited it in any way as it's part of an assignment aside from entering the username and the password where the astericks are):

```
import pymysql
myConnection  = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='****', passwd='****', db='accidents')
cur = myConnection.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT vtype FROM vehicle_type WHERE  vtype LIKE "%otorcycle%";')
cycleList = cur.fetchall()
selectSQL = ('''
                SELECT  t.vtype, a.accident_severity
                FROM accidents_2016 AS a
                JOIN vehicles_2016 AS v ON  a.accident_index = v.Accident_Index
                JOIN vehicle_type AS t ON  v.Vehicle_Type = t.vcode
                WHERE t.vtype LIKE %s
                ORDER BY  a.accident_severity;''')
insertSQL = ('''INSERT INTO accident_medians  VALUES (%s, %s);''')

for cycle  in cycleList:
    cur.execute(selectSQL,cycle[0])
    accidents = cur.fetchall()
    quotient, remainder =  divmod(len(accidents),2)
    if  remainder:
        med_sev =  accidents[quotient][1]
    else:
        med_sev =  (accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+2][1])/2
    print('Finding median  for',cycle[0])
    cur.execute(insertSQL,(cycle[0],med_sev))
myConnection.commit()
myConnection.close()
```

I did the import with the pymysql and installed it via the command line. Additionally, after reading a few other responses due to other errors, I installed the pop cryptography as well. Each time I run the script, I get a new error. Now when I run it, it gives me a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/School/ITS 410/Mod 8/Portfolio.py", line 22, in <module>
    med_sev =(accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+2][1])/2
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I have only seen this one other time and it was also in Python but I don't remember what it means or how I fixed it.

Comment: What about searching `IndexError: tuple index out of range`?

Comment: I did search for that and none of the answers that I found were helpful with this specific code. They all regarded the index and the numbers possibly being wrong and how Python is 0-based. I have switched the numbers multiple times and nothing. Still the same error.

Comment: Copy paste the full traceback of the error.

Comment: i edited the question with the complete traceback error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying that on this line:

```
med_sev =(accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+2][1])/2
```

you are trying to index something that doesn't exist. I imagine it is on the part `accidents[quotient+2][1]` because this is the greater indexed one. What does this mean? Well suppose that accidents is something like

```
accidents = [[thing0, thing1], [thing2, thing3]]
```

now say the quotient is 0, so you're code evaluates accidents[2][1]. This doesn't make sense because accidents[0] is `[thing0, thing1]`, and accidents[1] is `[thing2, thing3]`, but there is no accidents[2]. Therefore when Python goes to look find it and assign it to the value `med_serv` it can't. You can verify and debug the error with:

```
accidents = cur.fetchall()
quotient, remainder =  divmod(len(accidents),2)
if  remainder:
    print("quotient: {}".format(quotient))
    print("accidents: {}".format(accidents))
    med_sev =  accidents[quotient][1]
else:
    print("quotient: {}".format(quotient))
    print("accidents: {}".format(accidents))
    med_sev =  (accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+2][1])/2
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This explained things quite well. I was able to change up the quotients so that the numbers matched what Python was actually looking for. Thank you for explaining it like this.