# list index out of range in sql python script

Tags: python, mysql

```
 for cycle in cycleList:
     cur.execute(selectSQL,cycle[0])
     accidents = cur.fetchall()
     quotient, remainder = divmod(len(accidents),2)
     if remainder:
         med_sev = accidents[quotient][1]
     else:
         med_sev = (accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+2][1])/2
     print('Finding median for',cycle[0])
     cur.execute(insertSQL,(cycle[0],med_sev))
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "< stdin >", line 8, in < module >
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Forgive me if the solution is incredibly obvious. I am **really** new to this, taking a database class, and I've already been trying to deal with the whole script for hours. I was just supposed to copy+paste from my teacher and run it, but as you can see since I am here, that didn't work.

Changing 
`med_sev = (accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+2][1])/2`
to 
`med_sev = (accidents[quotient][1] + accidents[quotient+1][1])/2`
does not work, either, as someone suggested.

Edit: [Tuple Errors Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624168/tuple-errors-python) has an almost identical issue (except mine says "list", not "tupe". Reedinationer's debug script just gave me back the same error I was dealing with before. The OP mentioned how they were "able to change up the quotients so that the numbers matched what Python was actually looking for" but did not provide them.

Answer (score 0):

```
quotient, remainder = divmod(len(accidents),2)
```

If `len(accidents)=0` then `quotient=0, remainder=0` so accidents is actually empty so whatever index you access it will be out of range.

I would suggest checking what `len(accidents)` is.